# node proxy closed connection unexpectedly

Tags: python, apache, node.js, proxy

my system runs python code with apache and mod_wsgi.

node proxyes the connection to apache.

in the python script i serve a file in response to a http get.

when requesting the connction cuts unexpectedly in the middle.

the node code:

> var server =  https.createServer(httpsOptions,function (req, res) {

```
var result=req.url.match(/^\/(.*?)(\/.*?)$/);
    if (!(result&&result[1]=='socket.io')) {
        return proxy.proxyRequest(req, res);
    }
});
```

when i make the request to apache if works fine.
it also works fine for the first request affter a node restart.

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js proxy server posts to http server and dies when http server is closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286326/node-js-proxy-server-posts-to-http-server-and-dies-when-http-server-is-closed)